# do while looping forever

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm having trouble with this method, I'm forever stuck on "Sorry you must specify a Deeppan or thin base, try again: " even if I type jimmy, harry, deeppan, thin, Thin.. etc After I type either deeppan or thin, I want the String stored in the variable "size" and returned

Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
 public String Input(){


    String size;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("thin or thick: ");

    do {
        size = scan.next();
        if ( !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thick") || !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thin" )) {
            System.out.print("Sorry you must specify a thick or thin base, try again: ");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while ( true );

    return size;
}
```

Comment: It will keep going until while() is not true, but you set it to always be true.

Comment: He has a break statement if the conditional does not evaluate to true, that should work.

Comment: You have to use the debugger and evaluate the two expressions in the if. Using parentheses always helps in this kind of situations, because it is easier to read which expression will be evaluated first...

Comment: I think it needs to be `&&` possibly?

Comment: Less than 24 hours ago we helped you with this exact issue. You have learn how to make a correct boolean expression.

Comment: Me being here, asking questions, is me learning.. that's why i'm asking questions. I'm sorry if after one question I can't solve (for me) quite complex boolean expressions. I've been learning java for a few weeks... I do apologise

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your || for a && in the if condition. At the moment the condition will be true if you type in 'thin' because it is not deeppan and vice versa.

Comment: This might be of interest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 5):

The statement inside your `if` is always `true`.

You should use either

```
!size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") && !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thin" )
```

or

```
!(size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thin" ))
```

Answer (score 2):

`while(true)` will make your loop infinite as its always true

reason is you are doing `||` operation

Answer (score 2):

reason:

```
!size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") || !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thin" )
```

`size` cannot be "Deeppan" and "thin" at the same time :-)

try:

```
  do {
        size = scan.next();
        if (size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") || size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thin" )) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Sorry you must specify a Deeppan or thin base, try again: ");
        }
    } while ( true );
```

ps. "size" isn't the best variable name...

Answer (score 1):

No reason to use a `do-while`, try a `while` like this, the condition checking becomes more straightforward:

```
while (true) {
    size = scan.next();
    if (size.equalsIgnoreCase("deeppan") || size.equalsIgnoreCase("thin"))
         return size;
    System.out.println("Sorry you must specify a Deeppan or Thin base, try again:");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always be true, and therefore never reach the `else`

Example 1: Size is "Deeppan":
!size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") || !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thin")
= !true || !false
= false || true
= true

Example 2: Size is "foo":
  !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") || !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thin")
 = !false || !false
 = true || true
 = true

Answer (score 0):

Yuor statement

if ( !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "Deeppan") || !size.equalsIgnoreCase( "thin" ))

is always true.